# Youtube video iframe API - How to pause the video when it looses focus?

Tags: jquery, video, iframe, youtube, pause

I'm using the Youtube video iframe API and everything works perfect. There's only one thing left for it to work as i spected:
I want to detect when the video focus is out, even if it happends in the same window or browser tab, for it to stop playing, or pause.

i have been trying with jquery:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        player.blur(function(){
            $(this).stopVideo();
        });
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seems to work. Can somebody help?

Comment: Is the video created dynamically? If so, you need to bind it on a parent object of some kind. Also, you can try the .on('focusout', function(){}) style of losing focus.

Comment: Yes, it is loading dinamically. So, you say i can achieve this by doing this: `$('#video-parent).on('focusout', function(){});`.

Comment: It is not working. Can you please post an example?

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching an on method as such:

```
$('#parentElement').on('focusout', '.playerSelector', function() { //DO STUFF// });
```